# NGRX 8 add element to array in store

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-store

I am working with Angular ngrx 8. And I have a problem with redux.

When I have below interface:

```
export interface PersonChecklist {
    personName: string;
    isChecked: boolean;
}
```

I would like to have person array on the store.

Action:

```
export const savePersonToChecklist = createAction(
    '[PERSON_API] Save person to checklist array',
    props<{
        personName: string;
    }>()
);
```

Reducer:

```
on(savePersonToChecklist, (state, action) => ({
        ...state,
        jobStatus: {
            ...state.jobStatus,
            personsReadyForChecklist:
                [
                    {
                        ...state.jobStatus.personsReadyForChecklist,
                        personName: action.personName,
                        isChecked: true
                    }
                ]

        }
    }))
```

I saved nested entry per every dispatch action... I would like have below structure:

```
[
{personName: 'A',
 isChecked: true},
{personName: 'B',
 isChecked: true},
.
.
.]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a couple of things you need to fix to make this work correctly:

```js
on(savePersonToChecklist, (state, action) => ({
    ...state,
    jobStatus: {
      ...state.jobStatus,
      ordersReadyForChecklist: [
        ...state.jobStatus.ordersReadyForChecklist,   // <-- This needs to be here
        {
          personName: action.personName,   // <-- This needs to be "personName" not "workOrderNumber"
          isChecked: true
        }
      ]
    }
}))
```

I have created a working example on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-twyfcx), I hope I guessed correctly your requirements...

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

```
[
      ...state.jobStatus.ordersReadyForChecklist,
                {
                    personName: action.personName,
                    isChecked: true
                }
  ]
```

And try do use payload in action, it's a good practice.
eg:

```
{payload: {personName: string}}
```

Comment: I have an error: 'TypeError: undefined is not iterable (cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.iterator)) at push...' and it is strange, because there is no any undefined.

Comment: do you initialize store property ( `ordersReadyForChecklist`) with empty array (`[]`) ?